# ReferenceError: loader is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been developing a React app with nodejs backend. Now I'm getting this error when I run `npm run build`. I have update node and npm to latest versions. I'm getting the following error log in the console.

```
$ npm run build

> client@0.1.0 build C:\Demos\mern-course\client
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/App.css
ReferenceError: loader is not defined

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My package.json is as follows.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Here is the link for github repo for the code.](https://github.com/chathuradevinda/poc_mern_stack_shopping_list)

Comment: the Error details you added doesn't have `ReferenceError: loader is not defined` Where is that shown?

Comment: Please provide more of the actual error above this line `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` in the terminal/console.

Comment: @Chathura Devinda please edit your question.

Comment: compiler shows error is in your app.css file, can you go through the file and check for 'loader' inside the file

Comment: @AkhilAravind app.css file only contained some css styles. I have replace all the default content in the initial creat-react-app template.

Comment: Do a grep on 'loader'  and check

Comment: @AkhilAravind still no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
./src/App.css
ReferenceError: loader is not defined
```

You need to check that you are importing `App.css` correctly. This should be in your App.js

Comment: Thank you @Afia. Since both App.css and App.js are in the same level, import in App.js could not be wrong.

Comment: Hi @ChathuraDevinda, Are you able to resolve this issue? If not, Try removing the css from App.js and try building again. But before that, check the console for any error or warning messages.

Comment: Hi @Afia after several attempts I tried creating a new project and it worked. So I replaces the css-loader folder and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Replace "css-loader" folder in front end node-modules folder with another "css-loader" which has taken from working react project.